# application should minimize on backkey press

Tags: android

In my application I have a requrement like, If I press backkey application should not exit(as i have only one activity in my app) instead it should minimize the app as like its happening with the home key press.
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: I don't know about the feasibility of this, but I believe this is NOT a good practice. Users expect an app to be closed when they press the Back button. What is the point of leaving your app running in the background ?

Comment: That's a good practice if OP wants to save app state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

// Add this line inside back pressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
   moveTaskToBack(true);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just save whatever you need in `Activity.onSaveInstanceState()` and restore the saved info in `Activity.onRestoreInstanceState` as in this example [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)